# Why cant I connect to my server (Connection attempt failed)

Tags: c#, smtp, mailkit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FacWE.png)I used mailkit and works 100% with outlook smtp but not my own domain.

```
 using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {

                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
                client.Connect(SmtpServer, SmtpPortNumber, /*SecureSocketOptions.Auto*/ /*SSL*/true);
                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication 
                // Error 5.5.1 Authentication  
                client.Authenticate(UsernameD, PasswordD);
                client.Send(mimeMessage);

                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
```

the catch clause:

catch (Exception ex)
            {

```
            //when any error occurrs in this method the error message is written in the log file (log.txt) which is located in the root.
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(LogError, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Message :" + ex.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace +
                   "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            Application.ExitThread();
            Application.Exit();
```

Comment: What line throws an exception? What is the type of the exception? What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: client.Connect(SmtpServer, SmtpPortNumber, /*SecureSocketOptions.Auto*/ /*SSL*/true);  It throws the error here saying Server took too long to respond

Comment: Please update your post to specify that. You still haven't told us what `ex.GetType` and `ex.StackTrace` is.

Comment: Sorry im quite new , please seee the link in header@mjwills

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don’t have a firewall on your desktop blocking you from connecting to your server. Also make sure that the server does not have a firewall blocking incoming connections on whatever port the smtp service is running on (25? 465? 587?)